# System.net.webexception in system.dll

Tags: c#, rest, powerbi

I have followed this tutorial to update a powerbi dashboard [here](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-walkthrough-push-data/).

I have copied all the code from Microsoft's website. Of course I have supplied my own `clientId`.

The console application successfully creates a dataset, but does not add rows to the table.

It fails here:

```
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
>
> Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

Comment: Are you able to ping the url?

Comment: 404 Not Found is a HTTP status code and mean the URL you request is not found, can you post the URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL you are querying is wrong or no longer exists. Check the documentation for the APIs you are querying to make sure you are properly constructing the URL.

Start here for PowerBI APIs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn877544.aspx